# jquery: .change() only fires after focus is away, cant use keyup()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple form field with login information.
I want jquery to handle the match logic. I did this:

```js
    function EnableButton(mode) {
        document.getElementById("submit")[(mode ? "remove" : "set") + "Attribute"]("disabled", mode);
    }
    $("input").change(function () {
         //alert($(this).val());
         var email = $("[name='emailaddress']").val();
         var email2 = $("[name='emailaddress2']").val();
         var pw = $("[name='pw']").val();
         var pw2 = $("[name='pw2']").val();
         var telephone = $("[name='telephone']").val();
         const cb = document.querySelector('#ag');
    
    
         if(email == '') {
             EnableButton(false)
             return;
         }
    
         if (email2 == '') {
             EnableButton(false)
             return;
         }
    
         if (pw == '') {
             EnableButton(false)
             return;
         }
    
         if (pw2 == '') {
             EnableButton(false)
             return;
         }
    
         if(email != email2){
             alert('Email sind ungleich.')
             EnableButton(false)
             return;
         }
    
         if (pw != pw2) {
             alert('Passwörter sind ungleich.')
             EnableButton(false)
             return;
         }
    
         if (cb.checked) EnableButton(true)
         else EnableButton(false)
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name='emailaddress'>
<input type="text" name='emailaddress2'>
<input type="password" name='pw'>
<input type="password" name='pw2'>
<input type="number" name='telephone'>
<input type="checkbox" id="ag">
<input type="button" disabled id="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="alert('clicked')">
```

Now, this function works fine. It checks for all inputs type=password and type=text and even type=checkbox.

However, it only fires AFTER the user is done typing information into the frontend.
That means that the user could technically fill out everything until it is correct and then enable the login button but before clicking that, he could remove input from any field (or just alter it) and without losing the focus click on the still enabled login button. Then he would bypass my checkup function and the user would be able to create a faulty user.

If I now change .change() to .keyup() this function is fired irregadless of if the user is done typing or not, it just fires every time.
So far, so good, however i cannot attach this to my input = checkbox input. Keyup wont trigger with a checkbox.

How can I combine input=password, input=text and input=checkbox all in one immediately responding function?

Comment: Your JS is invalid, you have syntax errors around your selector strings. Review the snippet, and make sure it reflects your actual code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event: _"Note: The `input` event is fired every time the value of the element changes. This is unlike the `change` event, which only fires when the value is committed, such as by pressing the enter key, selecting a value from a list of options, and the like."_

Comment: I mean... what's wrong with each input type having an appropriate event? what's wrong with *also* triggering validation on submit? It seems like you're taking a few unnecessary shortcuts just because you want less code... even though that has no real benefit on the end-user.

Comment: I dont know whats going on here, but this is not the js that i posted. it has been altered quite a bit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change your `change` event into an `input` event, like this:

```js
        function EnableButton(mode) {
            document.getElementById("submit")[(mode ? "remove" : "set") + "Attribute"]("disabled", mode);
        }
        document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
            handleForm(true);
            if (!this.disabled) alert('clicked');
        });
        function handleForm(isFullValidation) {
         //alert($(this).val());
         var email = $("[name='emailaddress']").val();
         var email2 = $("[name='emailaddress2']").val();
         var pw = $("[name='pw']").val();
         var pw2 = $("[name='pw2']").val();
         var telephone = $("[name='telephone']").val();
         const cb = document.querySelector('#ag');
    
    
         if(email == '') {
             EnableButton(false)
             return;
         }
    
         if (email2 == '') {
             EnableButton(false)
             return;
         }
    
         if (pw == '') {
             EnableButton(false)
             return;
         }
    
         if (pw2 == '') {
             EnableButton(false)
             return;
         }
         
         if (isFullValidation) {
             if(email != email2){
                 alert('Email sind ungleich.')
                 EnableButton(false)
                 return;
             }
    
             if (pw != pw2) {
                 alert('Passwörter sind ungleich.')
                 EnableButton(false)
                 return;
             }
         }
    
         if (cb.checked) EnableButton(true)
         else EnableButton(false)
     }
    $("input").on("input", function() {handleForm(false)});
    $("input").change(function() {handleForm(true)});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name='emailaddress'>
<input type="text" name='emailaddress2'>
<input type="password" name='pw'>
<input type="password" name='pw2'>
<input type="number" name='telephone'>
<input type="checkbox" id="ag">
<input type="button" disabled id="submit" value="SUBMIT">
```

I took the liberty of separating your email and password validation, so you will not get an alert warning you about email/password mismatch while these values are being typed in.

Comment: Can someone describe what needs to be improved in this answer? I have edited the question, fixing the syntax errors and converting the code into a snippet and then provided an answer to it. If someone found a problem with it, then I would be glad to understand it so I could improve my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @inno thank you for the reply. I have edited your question, because the code there had some syntax errors and the HTML was missing. I have modified that code to make sure that it illustrates the problem and used that code as a starting point in my answer. I did not have your HTML, nor your `EnableButton` function, so I have implemented something for those in order to "fill the gap" and make sure that the code is reproducible and illustrates the problem. Please let me know if the edit was incorrect, I'm happy to change it to something closer to what you had.

Comment: ah, that explains it ^^